# the half of the screen does not seem to work correctly

Tags: unity, screen

I am not such a professional coder but trying to code something on Unity. However, when I try to play the application in my android phone, the half of the screen does not seem to work correctly:

[image]
[image]

Can you guess what the reason is for that?

Up to now, I have changed screen resolution but it did not solve my problem.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's not a resolution issue. It's a sorting order issue. Also, that specific image and text is better off as GUI

Comment: I have had the exact same problem, this would only happen on android.  It ended up being a camera culling issue with the distances of the scene objects in relation to the camera.

Answer (score 1):

After changing Main Camera setting according to this photo: [image] , I have solved my problem.

@Jon might have said same thing but my English was not enough to understand. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Gameobjects with same coordinates or depth values sometimed cause jitter or overlap (as seen in your question). Try changing depth or sorting axis.